# Tools to crawl a site and compile payload statistics for each URL?

Tags: performance, http, curl, seo, wget

My goal is to crawl a given site, and log statistics for the total payload of each page on the site. By payload I mean the number of bytes once the original document, css, js, images, etc... are downloaded. I'm attempting to put together a graph which will show the "heaviest" pages on my site so that those can be dealt with first.

Does anyone know of any tools or techniques to do this? My preference is something that would integrate well with a web app, in PHP or Python.

Comment: If you just want the end data, perhaps pre-written tools such as [Yahoo's yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) might save you some time. If you want the fun project, then have fun. :)

Comment: Well aware of YSlow, and it does exactly what I want, however I'm looking for something I can build into a script -- so YSlow is not ideal for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen [plenty of questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mechanize) about [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), they usually look like they get a lot done with only a little bit of code.